# How do I show that the map $p: X \to Y$, defined below, is a closed map?

Tags: general-topology

$X = [0, 1] \cup [2, 3]$ and $Y=[0, 2]$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}.$ The map $p: X \to Y$ is defined as

$$p(x)= \begin {cases} x&\text{if }x \in [0, 1]\\
x-1\
&\text{if }x \in [2,3]\\ \end {cases}$$

The author writes that the map is readily seen to be a closed map. I tried taking a closed set in $X$ and its image under the map $p$ was closed in $Y$, but I'd like to know how should one prove in general that image of any closed set is closed.

Answer (score 4):

your space X is compact in $\mathbb{R}$. Every closed subset of it is bounded, hence also compact. The image of a compact set under a continuous function is again compact and that equals bounded and closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That doesn't make it a closed map.

Comment: @squirrel Why would you consider the image of an open set, if we're looking for a closed map?

Comment: @JohnFernley: You know, I really have no idea what on Earth I was thinking. That was a truly bizarre, unrelated, and now deleted thought. Perhaps in my hasty reading, I thought jorst claimed that the image of any set would be closed.

Comment: I should add that I see nothing wrong with jorst's answer. It's a specific case for the general fact "continuous maps from a compact space to a Hausdorff space are closed."

Comment: Well there was no explicit invocation of such a theorem. It'd be a bit weird to only list conditions without at least "and so the map is closed" or something, what @jorst has given is definitely not definition

Comment: @John Fernley: This is the only correct answer given so far. jorst could have added a reference to the theorem he is referring to, but it is a standard fact one learns in a general topology class.

Answer (score 3):

every close of $X$ like $C$ is union of $C_1$ and $C_2$ that $C_1$ is a close from $[0,1]$ and $C_2$ is a close from $[2,3]$.

Now, image of $C_1$ and $C_2$ by $p$ is close because in the first case $p$ is identity map and in the second case $p$ is a map that re displaces the closed set. finally, the image of $C$ is union of two close that will be close.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't feel satisfied with this answer, though. How can you be sure that the image of $C_1$, say, is closed in $Y$? Yes the image is identity, but the two subspaces are not the same.

Comment: now you can use from the definition of closeness. for this get a sequance in image of $C_1$ that has limit and prove that the limit is in image.